# Error: unresolved reference: roundToInt

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to use `roundToInt()` to convert double value into rounded integer but I am getting `Unresolved Reference` exception.

I am going through the official [documentation of Kottlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/round-to-int.html) still no luck.

**Code:**

**Edit 1:**

```
fun solve(meal_cost: Double, tip_percent: Int, tax_percent: Int): Unit {
    var tip = (meal_cost *tip_percent)/100
    var tax = (meal_cost *tax_percent)/100
    var totalCost = (tip+tax+meal_cost).roundToInt()

    System.out.println("The total cost is "+totalCost+".")
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
Solution.kt:25:41: error: unresolved reference: roundToInt
var totalCost = (tip+tax+meal_cost).roundToInt()
                                    ^
```

Comment: What are the types of meal_cost, tip_percent and tax_percent? If they are `Int` tip and tax are also `Int`. Try `/100.0`

Comment: meal_cost  double variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`roundToInt()` is an extension function provided by the `math` package and not a member function of `Double`. To use it, you need to import the function:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

x.roundToInt()
```

Comment: so, what is the conclusion? How to use it?

Comment: Edited to add usage example.

Answer (score 0):

As `meal_cost`, `trip_percent` and `tax_percent` are integers `tip` and `tax` are also integers. This means `totalCost` has the type `Int`. `roundToInt()` is not defined for `Int`.

Change you `/100` to `/100.0` in order to divide by a double and the result will become a double as well.

```
var tip = (meal_cost *tip_percent)/100.0 // divide by double to make the result a double
var tax = (meal_cost *tax_percent)/100.0
var totalCost = (tip+tax+meal_cost).roundToInt() //Works now.
System.out.println("The total cost is "+totalCost+".")
```

Comment: meal_cost, is double variables